# automatic mount of an encrypted partition

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, luks

I have on my Ubuntu an encrypted partition (encrypted with cryptsetup).

Currently, I mount the partition with

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 backup && wait && sudo mount /dev/mapper/backup /backup
```

and it prompts for the paraphrase.

So is there a way to put this line in a script and mount automatically the partition (in order to do daily backup) like this:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 backup < paraphrase
```

or better:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 backup < hashed_paraphrase
```

Comment: Correct me if I get this wrong, but doesn't **any** "automated way to mount an encrypted partition" (without you entering the keyphrase) defeat the whole purpose of the encryption, by putting the key on a local drive (where it can be retrieved)?

Comment: cause this partition is my backup partition. and the key to decrypt it is on my home partition (also encrypted) :-) so if my server is shutting down, anyone can open any of the two partition, home and backup

Answer (score 2):

From the `cryptsetup(8)` man page:

> ```
>    --key-file, -d name
>           Read the passphrase from file.
>
>           If  the name given is "-", then the passphrase will be read from
>           stdin.  In this case, reading will not stop at  newline  charac‐
>           ters.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I create a random file

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/home/username/keyfile bs=1024 count=4 
chmod 400 /home/username/keyfile
```

then, I had the keyfile to my encrypted partition

```
 sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda1 /home/username/keyfile
```

And to mount automaticaly the partition:

```
sudo cryptsetup --key-file /home/username/keyfile luksOpen /dev/sda1 backup
```